# integral of irrational function (substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

\begin{array}{l}
\text{Integrate }\rm{  A = }\int {\frac{{1 - x}}{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} }}} dx\\
\\
{\text{We have }}\\
{\rm{x = a}} \cdot {\rm{sint}}\\
{\rm{dx = a}} \cdot {\rm{cost dt}}\\
\text{Find }\rm{  A = }\int {(1 - a \cdot \sin t)dt = ... = t + a\cos t}  + c\\
\sin t = \frac{x}{a}{\rm{ then t = Arcsin}}\left( {\frac{x}{a}} \right)\\
\text{Find }\rm{  A = Arcsin}\left( {\frac{x}{a}} \right) + \sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}}  + c\\
\\
\text{But the solution is }\\
{\rm{  }}\arctan [\frac{x}{{\sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} }}] + \sqrt {{a^2} - {x^2}} 
\end{array}

What is wrong?

Comment: I cleaned up some of the formatting for you if you don't mind

Comment: Ok.  Also   a is a positive real number

Comment: By the way these solutions are the same, if you draw the required triangle you can use arctangent or arcsine

Answer (score 2):

Noting is wrong.  Note that, for $a>0$
$$
\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)= \arctan \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \right)
$$

because, if :
$$
\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)=\alpha \quad \iff \quad \sin \alpha=\frac{x}{a}$$

we have:
$$
\cos \alpha =\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}
$$

and
$$
\tan \alpha=\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx+\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$

in the first, $x=at$ gives

$$I=\frac{a}{|a|}\arcsin(\frac{x}{a})+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+C$$